# How to generate address in metamask/coinbase progrematically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ethereum, metamask, coinbase-api, evm

I'm  planning to build a chrome extension that interacts with Metamask/Coinbase. I wonder if this is fisibile with the current Metamask API.

#### Question

I need to generate a new address on the user Metamask/Coinbase wallet from my chrome-extension. Is it possible?

#### Expected results

My chome-extentsion will try to reach out to the user's Metamask/Coinbase and create a new address. Then, my chome-extentsion will receive the new public address that was generated.

---

###### Attempts

I could not found something usefull here: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to generate a new address on the user Metamask/Coinbase wallet from my chrome-extension. Is it possible?

It is not possible. Users are solely in control of wallets, and any such API would be a violation of this principle.

Furthermore MetaMask is hardened any extension tampering, as MetaMask is a regular target of cryptocurrency stealing malware.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done. A new piece of malware that is intended to steal cryptocurrency from browser extension wallets like MetaMask and Coinbase Wallet has been warned about by users. Please get in touch with support@oscsystems.com for additional information.